# Shade area above y = x line for a scatter plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

So i've been trying draw a line of y = x on my scatter plot and shade the area above (y > x) in green.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend pos=north west,%
    xmode = log,
    ymode = log,
    title = Scatter plot of all tests,
    xlabel = {time A},
    ylabel = {time B}]
\addplot[
scatter,only marks, scatter src=explicit symbolic, 
scatter/classes={%
        ct={mark=square*,yellow},%
        dt={mark=triangle*,blue},%
        mp={mark=o, draw = pink, fill= pink},%
        md={mark=square*, orange},%
        pt={mark=triangle*, green}}
]
%
    table[x=x, y=y, meta=label] {
x     y      label

3.3   34.6   ct 
0.3   0.3   ct
0.7   0.6   ct
4.3   2.9   ct 
10.1   6.6   ct 
25.8   14.3   ct 
53.1   32.8   ct
116   77.4   ct
252.8   156.5   ct

0.2   0.4   dt
23.2   30.1   dt
0.1   0.4   dt
0.1   0.5   dt
0.1   0.7   dt
2.6   3.3   dt
3   3.7   dt
14.2   17.9   dt
0.1   0.4   dt
1.4   3.2   dt
3.7   10.2   dt
5.1   0.1   dt
15.9   0.2   dt
15.1   0.2   dt
38.7   0.8   dt


0.2   0.4   mp
0.4   0.6   mp
0.1   0.4   mp
0.8   2   mp
23.6   95.2   mp
1.1   3.2   mp
2   6.3   mp
2.2   8.4   mp

39   20.9   md
0.3   0.7   md
5.5   6.7   md
3.5   1.5   md
0.3   0.3   md
17.8   21.9   md
743.9   0   md
1.4   1.9   md
3.7   5.3   md
0.6   0.7   md
1.8   2   md
3.3   5.7   md
    };
    \legend{\tiny{\ac{CT}}, \tiny{\ac{DT}}, \tiny{\ac{MP}}, \tiny{\ac{MD}}}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I tried implementing the code with @marmot suggestions. I was able to shade a certain area, but it is always misaligned. I think its probably because of the log scale of both axes. I have no idea how to solve this issue (its been like 3 days since ive been trying to fix it. Im lost now).  [image: Plot rendered after suggestion]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! Drawing the line and shading the area is as simple as saying

```
\draw[fill=green] (0.001,0.001) -- (500,500) -| cycle;
```

I do not know the command `\ac` you are using so I had to make something up, but of course you can replace it by your command.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcommand{\ac}[1]{\textsf{#1}}%<- replace this by yours
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend pos=north west,%
    xmode = log,
    ymode = log,
    title = Scatter plot of all tests,
    xlabel = {time A},
    ylabel = {time B}]
\draw[fill=green] (0.001,0.001) -- (500,500) -| cycle;
\addplot[
scatter,only marks, scatter src=explicit symbolic, 
scatter/classes={%
        ct={mark=square*,yellow},%
        dt={mark=triangle*,blue},%
        mp={mark=o, draw = pink, fill= pink},%
        md={mark=square*, orange},%
        pt={mark=triangle*, green}}
]
%
    table[x=x, y=y, meta=label] {
x     y      label

3.3   34.6   ct 
0.3   0.3   ct
0.7   0.6   ct
4.3   2.9   ct 
10.1   6.6   ct 
25.8   14.3   ct 
53.1   32.8   ct
116   77.4   ct
252.8   156.5   ct

0.2   0.4   dt
23.2   30.1   dt
0.1   0.4   dt
0.1   0.5   dt
0.1   0.7   dt
2.6   3.3   dt
3   3.7   dt
14.2   17.9   dt
0.1   0.4   dt
1.4   3.2   dt
3.7   10.2   dt
5.1   0.1   dt
15.9   0.2   dt
15.1   0.2   dt
38.7   0.8   dt


0.2   0.4   mp
0.4   0.6   mp
0.1   0.4   mp
0.8   2   mp
23.6   95.2   mp
1.1   3.2   mp
2   6.3   mp
2.2   8.4   mp

39   20.9   md
0.3   0.7   md
5.5   6.7   md
3.5   1.5   md
0.3   0.3   md
17.8   21.9   md
743.9   0   md
1.4   1.9   md
3.7   5.3   md
0.6   0.7   md
1.8   2   md
3.3   5.7   md
    };
\legend{\tiny{\ac{CT}}, \tiny{\ac{DT}}, \tiny{\ac{MP}}, \tiny{\ac{MD}}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]